# Caching & GZip on GAE (Community Wiki)

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, gzip

Why does it seem like Google App Engine isn’t setting appropriate cache-friendly headers (like far-future expiration dates) on my CSS stylesheets and JavaScript files?   When does GAE gzip those files?  My `app.yaml` marks the respective directories as `static_dir`s, so the lack of far-future expiration dates is kind of surprising to me.

This is a community wiki to showcase the best practices regarding static file caching and gzipping on GAE!

Comment: To the person who voted to close because it is "not a real question", edit the question to put a few more question marks if you want.

Comment: never mind, i added the question marks myself.  For what it's worth, I would have asked this question pretty soon if the OP hadn't, as I have been wondering this myself after messing with YSlow

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## How does GAE handle caching?

It seems GAE sets near-future cache expiration times, but does use the `etag` header. This is used so browsers can ask, “Has this file changed since when it had a `etag` of `X68f0o`?” and hear “Nope – `304 Not Modified`” back in response.

As opposed to far-future expiration dates, this has the following trade-offs:

- Your end users will get the latest copies of your resources, even if they have the same name (unlike far-future expiration). This is **good**.
- Your end users will however still have to make a request to check on the status of that file. This does slow down your site, and is “pure overhead” when the content hasn’t changed. This is **not ideal.**

#### Opting for far-future cache expiration instead of (just) `etag`

To use far-future expiration dates takes two steps and a bit of understanding.

1. You have to manually update your app to request new versions of resources, by e.g. naming files like `mysitesstyles.2011-02-11T0411.css` instead of `mysitestyles.css`. There are tools to help automate this, but I’m not aware of any that directly relate to GAE.
2. Configure GAE to set the expiration times you want by using `default_expiration` and/or `expiration` in `app.yaml`. [GAE docs on static files](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Handlers)

#### A third option: Application manifests

Cache manifests are an HTML5 feature that overrides cache headers. [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Offline_resources_in_Firefox), [DiveIntoHTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html), [W3C](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html). This affects more than just your script and style files' caching, however. Use with care!

## When does GAE `gzip`?

According to [Google’s FAQ](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#compression),

> Google App Engine does its best to serve gzipped content to browsers that support it. Taking advantage of this scheme is automatic and requires no modifications to applications.
>
> We use a combination of request headers (Accept-Encoding, User-Agent) and response headers (Content-Type) to determine whether or not the end-user can take advantage of gzipped content. This approach avoids some well-known bugs with gzipped content in popular browsers. To force gzipped content to be served, clients may supply 'gzip' as the value of both the Accept-Encoding and User-Agent request headers. Content will never be gzipped if no Accept-Encoding header is present.
>
> This is covered further in the runtime environment documentation ([Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#Responses) | [Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Responses)).

Some real-world observations do show this to generally be true. Assuming a gzip-capable browser:

- GAE gzips actual pages (if they have proper `content-type` headers like `text/html; charset=utf-8`)
- GAE gzips scripts and styles in `static_dir`s (defined in `app.yaml`).
- Note that you should not expect GAE to gzip  images like GIFs or JPEGs as they are already compressed.

Comment: You can set expirations on the static handlers in the app.yaml, see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Handlers

Comment: `You have to manually update your app to request new versions of resources, by e.g. naming files like mysitesstyles.2011-02-11T0411.css instead of mysitestyles.css.` This seems like a version-control nightmare. Why not instead just append a query string to the end of the CSS files, like mysitestyles.css?v=2012-5-10. You won't duplicate files, and you'll also be able to serve fresh files to users when updating your app. While CSS files don't use query strings, browsers cache the resource using the full URI as the key, not just the filename. If I'm missing something here, please let me know.